# Remove bound items from ListBox only when user clicks save button

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, updatesourcetrigger

I have items bound to a listbox and I've implemented a function to delete them when they're selected and the user presses the Delete key.  Currently, the delete function directly accesses the source.  However, I don't want to modify the source unless the user clicks a save button first.

How could I modify deleting ListBoxItems so my source isn't updated until the user clicks a button?

List I bind to

```
public ObservableCollection<Process> Processes { get; set; }
```

Delete function

```
private void OnDeletePressed(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
    {
        foreach (Process item in ProcessListBox.SelectedItems.OfType<Process>().ToList())
        {
            SelectedRobot.Processes.Remove(item);
        }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<ListBox x:Name="ProcessListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Processes, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" KeyDown="OnDeletePressed">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding ProcessName}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Maybe you have a property on Process object called IsDeleted and set that to true when the user clicks delete button and then remove the item from the list when the user clicks save?

Comment: Further to the comment by @Krishna you could add a data trigger to the item template that (based on the `IsDeleted` property being set to `true`) sets the visibility of the item to `Collapsed` and sets the parent **ListBoxItem**'s `Focusable` property to `false`. This way the item will "disappear" from view but will still be in the source list.

Comment: @StevenRands Another way would be bind to ICollectionView and have a filter on IsDeleted. That way, the item will be gone from the UI collection but will still be there in the source collection :)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create a copy of your collection and maintain the original. For example, somewhere in initialization, call:

```
    List<Process> pOriginalList = null;

    pOriginalList = Processes.ToList();



    private void OnDeletePressed(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
        {
            foreach (Process item in ProcessListBox.SelectedItems.OfType<Process>().ToList())
            {
                this.Processes.Remove(item);
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnSaveClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // do nothing -- Processes already is set
    }

    private void OnCancelClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Processes.Clear();
        Processes = new ObservableCollection<Process>(pOriginalList);
        this.DataContext = null;
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ListCopy.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Save" Click="OnSaveClick" />
                <Button Content="Cancel" Click="OnCancelClick" />
            </StackPanel>
            <ListBox x:Name="ProcessListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Processes, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" KeyDown="OnDeletePressed">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Content="{Binding ProcessName}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This makes the operation explicit as to when you require an actual update to your source.  Note:  Setting DataContext like this is not recommended, just did it to enforce refresh of the list on Cancel.

Comment: I'd like to avoid making a copy & rebinding.  It seems like it should be possible to make changes that aren't applied to the source until the UpdateSourceTrigger is fired, just like the textbox property works.

Comment: Yes, for big lists I could see the motivation for that.  If you try removing the ListBox.Items with selected index it will throw exception: {"Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead."} which is pointing to your binding source (ItemsSource=Processes).  Not sure of a way to do this without making a copy.

Comment: If you want the actual item to disappear from list, keep as is, but create another list (removedList) and add the item to that list before you remove it.  If you hit save, keep Processes as is, otherwise add the items from removedList back to Processes.  This avoids the full copy. Employing the method Krishna suggests would require more work to remove (collapse) the item in list box but would also provide a way to create a custom user control that would delay updating the source automatically.